# How to get train and dev error in Keras neural net?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, evaluation

How should I get these values for the purpose of understanding whether my model is overfitting or underfitting? 
For instance, when `train_error= 0.1` and `dev_error=0.25`, it is understandable that the model is overfitted. But I don't know which of the provided results of my model indicates the mentioned errors.
Is the loss value indicating this measure or the (1-accuracy) one?

This is a part of my model's training result:

```
Epoch 152/250
100253/100253 [==============================] - 12s 118us/step - loss: 
0.5306 - acc: 0.8568 - val_loss: 1.1438 - val_acc: 0.7550
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the terms *error* and *loss* are synonyms
2. Keras indicates the training loss (respectively accuracy) as `loss` (`acc`); validation loss and accuracy are indicated as `val_loss` and `val_acc` respectively.
3. `train_error= 0.1` and `dev_error=0.25`, or `loss: 0.5306` and  `val_loss: 1.1438` as here, does **not** indicate overfitting; this is just the **generalization gap**, i.e. the expected gap in the performance between the training and validation sets. Quoting from a recent [blog post by Google AI](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html):

   > An important concept for understanding generalization is the *generalization gap*, i.e., the difference between a model’s performance on training data and its performance on unseen data drawn from the same distribution.

The telltale **signature** of overfitting is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image]

Notice the **gap** (pun intended) between the curves in the above plot (adapted from the [Wikipedia entry on overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)).

Depending on the context, one may prefer to monitor the *metric* instead of the loss as correctly pointed out in the comment below, but this is another discussion - hopefully you get the idea here...

Comment: I think it's valid to mention that sometimes, depending on your application, you might want actually use the metrics (instead of the loss) for determining where it will start overfitting. They don't always evolve the same way, and for certain purposes a metric is more important than a loss.

Comment: @DanielMöller Agree & updated answer; I am very happy you say so, because I recently stumbled upon a comment by a high-rep SO respondent on ML questions, claiming (erroneously, IMHO) that such an approach is wrong...

Comment: @desertnaut Yes I understood the concept of errors. Isn't it unnormal to have such big loss values? These ambiguous values made me wonder whether I understood the errors' concept correctly at first.

Comment: @DanielMöller I wanted to monitor my model on precision and recall values but I think there is no built-in methods for these purposes. Maybe I have to implement a custom metric for that!

Comment: @raminkarimian We usually cannot understand the cross-entropy loss intuitively, that's why we use the accuracy for this reason, which here does not look bad

Comment: @desertnaut So can I interpret the diagram of (1-acc) and (1-val_acc) values instead of loss and val_loss as evaluation purposes?

Comment: @raminkarimian You certainly can, but you can also use simply `acc` and `val_acc` themselves (in which case your curves will be inverted - the higher the better)